# jQuery accordion arrowhead positions

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

My script is partially working, however the second click does not return the arrowheads (arrowIcon class) to their original state. What Am I missing;

```
$('.expand .show').click(function (){
  $(this).parent().find('div.slide').slideToggle('fast');
  $(this).find('.arrowIcon').slideDown(function (){
    if ($(this).css('backgroundposition-y') < 0){
      $(this).css({'background-position':'0px 0px'});
    } else {
      $(this).css({'background-position':'0px -14px'})
    }
  });
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't the CSS property background-position-y and not "backgroundposition-y" ?

Comment: I've tested both and they work fine, I imagine background-position-y is the correct syntax though...

Comment: @webworker: No. `$(this).css("backgroundposition-y")` will not return the same value as `$(this).css("background-position-y")`: http://jsbin.com/alogiq